# Class 'CHtml' not found in Gridview in Yii2

Tags: php, gridview, yii2, yii-chtml

I am developing Yii2 application where I want to list orders data in GridView.

User can click on order id and will be redirected to another GridView with order details listing. I want to display link with order id to redirect to order details page.

But I got the following error:

> Class 'CHtml' not found

in GridView. Here is my code:

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
         ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
         [
             'attribute'  => 'id',
             'value' => CHtml::link("Link", Yii::app()->createUrl("user/view")),
             'format'  => 'raw',
         ],
         'user_id',
         'amount',
         'promo_code_used',   
         ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
    ],
]) ?>
```

Comment: I recommend to read the docs before asking such questions. There are many changes in Yii2 compare to first version.

Comment: Sure@arogachev I will check it first now. Thanks for suggestion

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Thers is no `CHtml` in `Yii2`. Use `Html` helper instead (see docs [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-helper-html.html#hyperlinks) and [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-basehtml.html#a%28%29-detail)). For generating hyperlink use `Html::a()` instead of `Chtml::link()`. So the code will be like this:

```
use yii\helpers\Html;    

...

echo Html::a("Link", ["user/view"]);
```